# Code Quality and Unit Testing for a Landing Page

Tags: unit-testing, web

I'm creating a personal portfolio landing page using react. This is just a simple landing page with static content so far.

Lately, I have been writing unit tests to my code on other projects, so I wonder, is there any way to make unit tests to this kind of website? Or is there no reason at all to do this?

Is there any other kind of test that I can make to check the stability and quality of my code?

Comment: If you want to: if there is code that is run, why not test it? If you don't see any need for this: why not skip it?

Comment: I got what you said, but this will lead me to not do tests when there is a way to do it. That's why I asked. I want to know if there is a way that I'm ignoring right now.

Comment: So, if there is a way to write tests, why not do it? If that is a React project, there should be tons of tutorials out there to get your started